# How to Pass single data to antd dropdown

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, antd

I am trying to pass a single data to the dropdown menu component.

I fetched the data from the database and I want to pass each id to the dropdown

Unexpected Application Error!
React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.

```
const TabPanel = ({ id }) => {

    const [winningTags, setWinningTags] = useState()
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getWinningTags() {
            const res = await CategoryServices.getWinningTags(id);
            setWinningTags(res.data.data)
        }
        getWinningTags(id)
    }, []);


    return (
        <div className="d-flex flex-wrap align-item-center">
            {winningTags && winningTags.map((winningTag) => (
                <div key={winningTag.id}>
                    <Card bordered={true} style={{ width: 300 }}>
                        <img src={sam} alt="" />
                        <div className="d-flex">
                            <div>
                                <header className='my-3 bold'>
                                    {winningTag.name}
                                </header>
                                <p>
                                    Current Price:  {winningTag.stake_price}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div className=''>
                                <Dropdown
                                    menu={{
                                        key: id,
                                        label: (
                                            <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.antgroup.com">
                                                Edit
                                            </a>
                                        ),
                                    }}
                                    placement="bottomRight"
                                >
                                    <img src={more} alt="" style={{ "height": "50px", "cursor": "pointer" }} />
                                </Dropdown>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Card>

                </div>


            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default TabPanel
```